# No simple group of order $2025$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> There is no simple group of order $2025$.

If $G$ is simple then by the Sylow theorem, there must be $81$ Sylow $5$-subgroups and $25$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. Also, I can see that if Sylow $5$ subgroups intersect only on the identity element then $1944$ elements have order $5$ or $25,$ from here, Sylow $3$ subgroup must be unique hence normal and the assumption that $G$ is simple must be false. But I couldn't find a contradiction for distinct Sylow $5$-subgroups $P$ and $Q$ where $|P \cap Q|=5. $

My question is: How can I prove the rest of this argument? And could we solve the same problem if we work on Sylow 3-subgroups using the same argument?

Comment: If there are $81$ Sylow $5$-subgroups then there is a normal subgroup of order $81$ by Burnside's Transfer Theorem.

Comment: Or, avoiding BTT, if the intersection $R := P \cap Q$ of two Sylow $5$-subgroups has order $5$, then $N_G(R)$ contains $P$ and $Q$, and so it must contain $81$ Sylow $5$-subgroups, but then $N_G(R)=G$.

Comment: Burnside transfer theorem? Might as well just use that there are no odd simple groups if we are pulling out big guns. :) Presumably, this result is an exercise for someone first learning group theory.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thoroughly disagree! BTT is not a big gun, it is more like a pea shooter. It is such a useful tool in ruling out the existence of simple groups of specific small orders, that it makes no sense to attempt to avoid using it. The OP clearly knows Sylow's theorems, and the proof of BTT is no more difficult.

Comment: @DerekHolt well, it’s not the “all simple groups are even or cyclic” sort of big gun. That was a joke. But this is the sort of problem asked right after the Sylow theorems are proven. The goal is usually to allow the student to apply Sylow directly, to lay the groundwork for results like Burnside.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Yes, OK, but I have very kindly offered an alternative argument that just uses Sylow.